# Gatling: meaning of all fields in simulation.log file

Tags: stress-testing, gatling

I could not find any documentation other than four longs being the bytes received at the start and end regarding simulation.log file in Gatling output. Below is sample line from the log:

```
My scenario - Sync  7526052819726874465-2088    REQUEST     My Page 1404439715068   1404439715068   1404439716103   1404439716103   OK
```

What does all of this stand for? Should we have this information somewhere in the Gatling documentation?

Thanks

Edit----------------------------------------------------------------------

I browsed through Gatling source and found the [FileDataWriterSpec](https://github.com/excilys/gatling/blob/5ec2005aa05aa72d6a1a2234eb55f5d90576e616/gatling-core/src/test/scala/io/gatling/core/result/writer/FileDataWriterSpec.scala)
where outputting to the simulation.log is tested. According to this spec, we have an object [RequestMessage](https://github.com/excilys/gatling/blob/36075795d7376405d4c4ddacf3531a015ce3a606/gatling-core/src/main/scala/io/gatling/core/result/writer/DataWriterMessage.scala)
which is used as an object to carry the logged data. According to this class:

```
case class RequestMessage(
    scenario: String,
    userId: String,
    groupHierarchy: List[String],
    name: String,
    requestStartDate: Long,
    requestEndDate: Long,
    responseStartDate: Long,
    responseEndDate: Long,
    status: Status,
    message: Option[String],
    extraInfo: List[Any]) extends DataWriterMessage {
  def responseTime = responseEndDate - requestStartDate
}
```

above must be:
[scenario][userId][[groupHierarchy][name][first/last byte sent timestamp][first/last byte received timestamp][status]

Could anyone confirm? And what exactly is groupHierarchy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Missing recordType:

[scenario][userId][recordType][groupHierarchy][name][first/last byte sent timestamp][first/last byte received timestamp][status][extraInfo]

Regarding groups, see documentation: https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Structure-Elements#group

Answer (score 3):

I will quote [answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gatling/QfA0RrV2W_Q/4tzDAe2YAgAJ) of Gatling Lead Developer from 09/10/2015:

> simulation.log format is not documented for a good reason: it's not a public API and is subject to frequent changes.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at this repo: https://github.com/nuxeo/gatling-report/tree/master/src/main/java/org/nuxeo/tools/gatling/report

There are java parser implementations for different gatling versions. Reverse Engineering... but better than nothing